# java scriptの動きが反映されません

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui

htmlは苦手で，特にjava scriptの呼び出し方などわかっていない者です。

index.htmlで，

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="components/jquery.scrollablelink.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
</body>
</html>
```

と書いているのですが，

> DebugLogWarningError  iPad/8.4Onsen UI require jqLite. Load jQuery
>   after loading AngularJS to fix this error. jQuery may break Onsen UI
>   behavior.

と言われ，実行はされますが，別のページ(index.html以外のhtml)において，java scriptの動きが全く反映されていません．

コードを書く順番が間違っているのでしょうか．よろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 1):

恐らく `components/loader.js` の中でAngularJSが読み込まれていますが、これより先に `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` を読み込んでいるためそのエラーが出ているのだと思います。正常に動作させるには、AngularJSやOnsenUIより後にjQueryを読み込ませるようです（[参考](http://blog.asial.co.jp/1354)）。

ただ、MonacaではクラウドIDE上からMonaca向けのjQueryを組み込めるようですから、`jquery-**.js` を読み込むscriptタグを消して、こちらを使うとよいのではないでしょうか。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/manual/dependencies/components/

その他気になった点として・・・

- jquery-1.11.0.min.js と jquery-1.8.1.min.js の両方を読み込んでいますが、基本的に同じライブラリの違うバージョンを同時に使うことはできません。単に意味がないか、誤動作を起こすことがあります。
- jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css を読み込んでいますが、jQuery MobileのJSファイルが読み込まれていません。（CSS部分だけ使っているなら問題ありませんが）

Comment: @unqrist♦
unqrist♦さん
とても丁寧なアドバイスをありがとうございます．
scriptタグでのjsファイルの読み込み文はどちらも消し，早速コンポーネントにAngularを追加してhead内にライブラリを読み込むソース(教えてくださったリンク先を参照しました)を書き込みました．
しかしながらまだjava scriptの動きは反映されないまま実行されてしまいます．こうなるとjava script関係のソースの書き方が問題なのかもしれません．また，WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.というログも表示されるようになりました．もう少し頑張って直していこうと思います！

お忙しい中，対応してくださり本当にありがとうございます！もしまた何かアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: @user 混乱させてしまってすみません、head内に書くのはOnsenUIを単独で使う場合の話なので、MonacaでIDEからコンポーネント追加する場合はhead内でangularやらjqueryやら読み込む必要はありません。また、コンポーネントで追加する必要があるのはAngularではなくjQueryかと思います。

Comment: @unqrist♦ unqrist♦さん，折り返しありがとうございます．jQuey，追加しているのですがなかなかうまくいきません．unqrist♦さんのアドバイスを元に試行錯誤してみます！